# My spring boot app can't find its application.properties when launched out of eclipse

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, eclipse

I have a strange issue I can't solve:

Basically, I made a small spring boot application which is running correctly when launched from eclipse. My eclipse is the regular eclipse, not the Spring Tool Suite edition. App is launched as regular Java application, no extra parameters is provided to the app or JVM. What I've found was the contrary behaviour (working out of eclipse, but not inside).

As I'm using Maven to manage the dependencies of this app, I provided the maven assembly plugin configuration to build a fat jar, and I'm trying to execute the result with the following command: java -jar myJar.jar.

Spring is launched, but failed trying to fill the @Value(...) I have in the code:

```
java -Xmx2g -jar myJar.jar
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::               (v2.7.12)

Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hsqlServer' defined in class path resource [org/pepito/myjar/config/SpringConfig.class]: Unexpected exception during bean creation; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'hsqldb.server.database' in value "${hsqldb.server.database}"
...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'hsqldb.server.database' in value "${hsqldb.server.database}"
...
```

Obviously, this value is defined into the default application.properties, and this file in included into the fat jar, in the right place (classpath:/application.properties).

I also tried to add `--spring.config.location="classpath:application.properties"` to "force" the app to use this file, with no luck. I just can't understand why this is working with eclipse, and why not out of it. Eclipse is running on MacOS M2 (Java 8) while I'm trying to execute my app on a 32bit Linux Mint 19 with Java 8. Does it matter?

Java version is 1.8, maven configuration is :

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7.12</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.9.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>8</source>
                    <target>8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <finalName>myJar</finalName>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>
                                org.pepito.myjar.SpringBootTgApplication</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                    <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Main class is :

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootTgApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootTgApplication.class, args);
        try {
            new TelegramBotsApi(DefaultBotSession.class);
        } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

And my beans configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class SpringConfig {

    @Bean(initMethod = "start", destroyMethod = "stop")
    public Server hsqlServer(@Value("${hsqldb.server.database}") String dbType,
            @Value("${hsqldb.server.dbname}") String dbName,
            @Value("${hsqldb.server.no_system_exit}") Boolean noSystemExit,
            @Value("${hsqldb.server.port}") Integer serverPort,
            @Value("${hsqldb.server.remote_open}") Boolean remoteOpen) throws IOException, AclFormatException {
        Server bean = new Server();
        HsqlProperties props = new HsqlProperties();
        props.setProperty("server.database.0", dbType);
        props.setProperty("server.dbname.0", dbName);
        props.setProperty("server.no_system_exit", noSystemExit);
        props.setProperty("server.port", serverPort);
        props.setProperty("server.remote_open", remoteOpen);
        bean.setProperties(props);
        return bean;
    }

    @Bean
    @DependsOn("hsqlServer")
    public DataSource getDataSource(@Value("${hsqldb.datasource.driver-class-name}") String driverClassName,
            @Value("${hsqldb.datasource.url}") String url, @Value("${hsqldb.datasource.username}") String username,
            @Value("${hsqldb.datasource.password}") String password) {
        DataSourceBuilder<?> dataSourceBuilder = DataSourceBuilder.create();
        dataSourceBuilder.driverClassName(driverClassName);
        dataSourceBuilder.url(url);
        dataSourceBuilder.username(username);
        dataSourceBuilder.password(password);
        return dataSourceBuilder.build();
    }
}
```

Finally, my application.properties

```
server.port=28000
BOT_TOKEN=<token>
BOT_NAME=<value>
CCAA=<value>

hsqldb.server.database=file:<file>
hsqldb.server.dbname=<db name>
hsqldb.server.no_system_exit=true
hsqldb.server.port=9001
hsqldb.server.remote_open=true
hsqldb.datasource.driver-class-name=org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver
hsqldb.datasource.url=jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost/<db name>
hsqldb.datasource.username=<user>
hsqldb.datasource.password=<pass>

spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

logging.level.root=INFO
logging.level.org.pepito=TRACE
```

**UPDATE** It seems to be something related with the assembly plugin. Using the shade plugin to build the fat jar, it works correctly.

Comment: Check the file name of the jar with dependencies. According to the finalName in pom.xml provided it is something like myJar-whatever.jar. This one you should run and not myJar.jar

Comment: Yeah sorry, my mistake writing the question and changing names on the fly. In my case there's no name issue. As I said, I can run the app, but it's failing building the beans.